# Dynamically built sql server insert statement fails to insert

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-insert

We dynamically build a sql statement after validation

After running some code the generated values for the insert looks like this:

```
(1, 1, SYSDATETIME(), null),
(4, 1, SYSDATETIME(), null),
(6, 1, SYSDATETIME(), null),
(8, 1, SYSDATETIME(), null)
```

Valid SQL Syntax

We then user this as follows

```
IF(@Activities != null)
Begin
 INSERT INTO [User].[User_Activities]
       (UserId, ActivitieId, DateCreated, DateDeleted)
 VALUES
       @Activities
END
```

@Activities being the above dynamically built SQL statement, its throws an error saying incorrect syntax by @Activities.

Even though in SQL query window it looks like this:

```
Insert into [User].User_Activities
(UserId, ActivitieId, DateCreated, DateDeleted)
Values
(1, 1, SYSDATETIME(), null),
(4, 1, SYSDATETIME(), null),
(6, 1, SYSDATETIME(), null),
(8, 1, SYSDATETIME(), null)
```

and executes successfully, how can I make this work successfully via the application?

Comment: Parameters are not simply string-replaced into the statement, they're like variables in C#. This fails for the same reason you can't say `string s = "Console.WriteLine"; s("hello");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `@Activities` like this does not build a dynamic SQL statement. It combines a static part of a statement with a dynamic one, which is not possible in SQL Server.

You also have to correctly formulate the `IF` statement: `!=` operator cannot be used for inequality comparison against `NULL` value (it will never evaluate to `TRUE`). `IS NOT NULL` is used in this case.

You have to use `EXEC` to achieve what you want:

```
IF(@Activities IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
  EXEC('INSERT INTO [User].[User_Activities]
          (UserId, ActivitieId, DateCreated, DateDeleted)
        VALUES' + @Activities)
END
```

Comment: this is interesting, I have just tried your code I get no error, yet when viewing the database after the insert the records are not there

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at either `SqlBulkCopy` or table-valued-parameters. These offer a much cleaner way to insert multiple records into a SQL database from a C# app.